# How can I use modules in web2py?

Tags: function, module, import, include, web2py

I have some functions in `func.py` that I would like to access from my web2py controller called `default.py`. I tried to import and use `func.py` in `default.py` with "import func" and "calculatesomething = func.calculatesomething", but it doesn't work. The file `func.py` is also added in the Modules section of my web2py program.

Why it is not working? How can I make it to work? Should the module be in `func.py` or `default/func.py` or something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`func` has to be in a place that is in `PYTHONPATH` (sys.path) such as `web2py/site-packages`. This is the proper Pythonic way of doing it.

If instead you want to *package your module with your app*, then place it in `applications/yourapp/modules`, next, you should import it with `func = local_import('func')`

**Q:** People who are new to web2py may wonder: why use `local_import()` when the former method is the standard one in the Python world?

**A:** Because in web2py you can install new apps without restarting the server. Apps cannot change `sys.path` because it is not thread safe and would depend on the order those apps are installed. Moreover two apps may require modules with the same name but different (for example different versions). We want to avoid conflicts between those modules and other modules that may be pre-installed.

`local_import()` is a workaround that allows you to ship some modules with your apps and import them without adding the folder to `sys.path` and causing version conflicts.

Answer (score 38):

Just to add a bit to user570039's answer, local_import is documented [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Third-Party-Modules). It includes a `reload` parameter. According to the documentation:

> When you specify`reload=True`, it will re-import the module upon each request; otherwise your python process will only import the module once. The default is`reload=False`.

In development, setting `reload=True` can be convenient because changes to your module will work immediately without requiring a restart. However, re-importing upon each request will slow down performance, so `reload=False` is recommended in production.

---

**UPDATE:** Things have changed. **`local_import` has been deprecated**. If you have /applications/myapp/modules/mymodule.py, you can import it within myapp by doing:

```
import mymodule
```

web2py will check the application's "modules" folder before checking the rest of sys.path.

For more details, see [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules).

Comment: Thank you, guys! Both of these answers were very helpful!

Comment: How can I do this with folders? For example,
when I'm trying to import modules called `fuzz` and `process` in the  [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) library from `/applications/myapp/modules/fuzzywuzzy/` directory, using `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process` on GAE with Py2.7, I'm getting an `ImportError` saying `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named fuzzywuzzy`

Comment: I placed it in `web2py/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy` and am able to import them now :) ... But I still am interested in the possibility of having the module within the `web2py/applications/myapp/modules/` directory, especially because I don't want to accidentally break my older apps when I 'update' my modules for newer apps.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an `ImportError` even for the example above, i.e. `web2py/applications/myapp/modules/func.py` with `import func`, in my model `db.py` on Web2Py 1.99.7, on both GAE and when running `web2py.py` (Although, it works fine when `func.py` is placed in `web2py/site-packages/`)

Comment: Does your /modules folder contain an empty `__init__.py` file?

Comment: It didn't have it at first, but I still get the same ImportError even after placing it. (Tested on: GAE, PyPy and Python27)

Comment: web2py should also work if you put it in the modules folder and from applications.myapp.modules.fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

Comment: Since the original answer mentions `reload=True`, I think for a complete answer the update should include mention of `from gluon.custom_import import track_changes; track_changes(True)` as a replacement for `reload=True` functionality