# Accessing module installed on Pythonanywhere in Web2py

Tags: python, web2py, pip, import-module, pythonanywhere

I've used `pip-2.7 install --user soundcloud` to install the soundcloud module for Python 2.7 in Pythonanywhere.

In my Web2py App in Pythonanywhere, I get an error message when using `import soundcloud`, stating that the soundcloud module does not exist. Is it not possible to for Web2py to access a module installed on Pythonanywhere (that did not come pre-packaged)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as Web2Py can find it on the path then yes it will work. Before you try and import soundcloud you might need to do something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/markstadt/.local/lib/python/site-packages')
import soundcloud
```

Printing out sys.path from inside the web2py application and printing soundcloud.**file** from in a bash shell should give you all the information you need in order to add the correct directory to your path.

[Edited to add some extra info]

Web2Py has it's own site-packages folder that is automatically added to the path. See here:
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/178/ and [How can I use modules in web2py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657484/how-can-i-use-modules-in-web2py)

Comment: I opted to simply copy the module files into the app/modules directory as suggested in the links, because I wanted to avoid changed `sys.path`. Thanks for your help!